# How can I bind custom JS to a Wygwam field after it has intialised?

Tags: javascript, wygwam

I'm using EE 2.5.2 and Wygwam 2.6.3. I need to bind some custom javascript to a Wygwam field on the publish/edit screen in the CP once the field has initialised.

Specifically, I need to bind to something like this:

```
$(#cke_field_id_12).find('iframe').contents().find('body');
```

However as the iframe is created dynamically, I need to wait until after Wygwam has initialised for `$(#cke_field_id_12)` to have a child `iframe` plus contents for me to bind to.

Does CKEditor/Wygwam fire an event when it's ready that I can hook into to bind my functionality to? Or is the an alternative way to do this that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor’s instanceReady event ought to fit the bill for you:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#event:instanceReady

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    // ...
});
```